# output_from() function

Tags: specman

i'm new to specman.
how do i use the output_from() function. and what does it do?

Comment: You looked at the docs yet?  If you have a newer version of Specman (8.*+) then I'd recommend using the pdf.  I find `cdnshelp` to be very annoying.  Just go to the directory of your Specman install and look in docs for all the pdfs:  `find $SPECMAN_HOME/docs -name '*.pdf'`  If you have an older version of Specman (6.2 and before)  then the HTML/javascript browser is _very_ useful and helpful.  Too bad they threw that away when Cadence acquired Verisity.

Comment: indeed the cdnshelp didin't help me. i'll try to look up for the pdf. TNX

Comment: Oops, I guess the PDFs aren't in `$SPECMAN_HOME`, however you can download the PDFs from Cadence's website: http://sourcelink.cadence.com  then "resources" tab and "Product Manuals".  You'll have to create an account to log in. It was automatic for my @intel.com email account, but you may need to talk to them for whatever company you're working at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6.1.1 docs say:

25.8.4    `output_from()`

Purpose:

Collect the results of a system call

Category

Routine

Syntax :

```
output_from(command: string): list of string
```

Syntax Example

```
log_list = output_from("ls *log");
```

Parameter

`command`

A single operating system command, with or without parameters and enclosed in double quotes.

Description:

Executes the string as an operating system command and returns the output as a list of string. Under UNIX, stdout and stderr go to the string list.

Example

```
<' 
extend sys { 
    m1() is { 
        var log_list: list of string; 
        log_list = output_from("ls *log"); 
        print log_list; 
    }; 
}; 
'>
```